# Postgresql - как загрузить данные в таблицу из текстового файла, в Sql-запросе?

Tags: postgresql

Загрузка нужно именно из **текстового** файла или *.**csv**, но только через **sql запрос**, без tools вроде **pgql** и других.

При этом, чтобы работали относительные пути (путь до файла источника можно было указывать от корня, где находится sql файл.)

Можно ли это оформить в виде процедуры или функции, так как заполнение тестовыми данными, сгенерированными из случайных символов,
не очень читаемо, а если нужно загрузить несколько сотен пользователей с читаемыми именами и другими данными, то скрипт наполнения писать очень неудобно.

Есть вариант использовать **Liquibase** (loadData), но его нужно поднимать и настраивать для работы. Хотелось бы более простой способ, если конечно он есть.

```sql
CREATE TABLE weather
(
    city    varchar(80),
    temp_lo int,  -- низкая температура --
    temp_hi int,  -- высокая температура --
    prcp    real, -- количество осадков --
    date    date
);

COPY weather FROM './weather.txt';
```

weather.txt

```
'San Francisco', 43, 57, 0.0, '1994-11-29'
'London', 45, 56, 0.1, '1994-11-30'
'Berlin', 35, 46, 0.2, '1994-11-15'
```

Этот вариант не работает.

> Файлы, указанные в команде COPY, читаются или записываются непосредственно сервером, не клиентским приложением. Поэтому они должны располагаться на сервере или быть доступными серверу, а не клиенту. Они должны быть доступны на чтение или запись пользователю PostgreSQL (пользователю, от имени которого работает сервер), не клиенту. Аналогично, команда, указанная параметром PROGRAM, выполняется непосредственно сервером, а не клиентским приложением, и должна быть доступна на выполнение пользователю PostgreSQL. Выполнять команду COPY с файлом (или командой) разрешено только суперпользователям базы данных, так как она позволяет прочитать и записать любой файл, к которому имеет доступ сервер.

Хорошо, чтобы решение работало как в Windows среде, так и в Ubuntu.

Comment: У вас есть уникальный шанс - написать такую функцию или программу ;)

Comment: `Относительные пути` - относительно чего? `без tools` - а запрос, кто будет исполнять? Какая программа? Вами написанная? Я не понимаю постановку задачи, нужны ответы на эти вопросы

Comment: Сервер postgresql физически не может обращаться ни к каким файлам, которые расположены не на нем. Что собственно и написано в аннотации к COPY. Что бы доступ был, должна быть программа которая эти данные прочитает и передаст по сети. И это должна быть программа написанная вами (либо кем то еще, вроде тех самых "tools" которыми вы пользоваться не хотите).